# read Variables from a json file to a windows form application

Tags: json, vb.net

I am writing a Visual Basic Application that retrieves data from a 
Node.js Api Call to a webservice.

The Node Program sends a request to the webservice API and recieves the response in a JSON Format  as listed below.

I am Writing a Visual Basic Windows FORMS Application to READ the JSON Format result that has arrived into the console.  HOW do I put the result into VARIABLES as arrays to be used in a windows Forms Application.
How do I parse the Console data into array variables....in a VB Windows FORMS Application?

here is the result to be captured:

```
 {
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "MarketName" : "BTC-888",
            "High" : 0.00000919,
            "Low" : 0.00000820,
            "Volume" : 74339.61396015,
            "Last" : 0.00000820,
            "BaseVolume" : 0.64966963,
            "TimeStamp" : "2014-07-09T07:19:30.15",
            "Bid" : 0.00000820,
            "Ask" : 0.00000831,
            "OpenBuyOrders" : 15,
            "OpenSellOrders" : 15,
            "PrevDay" : 0.00000821,
            "Created" : "2014-03-20T06:00:00",
            "DisplayMarketName" : null
        }, {
            "MarketName" : "BTC-A3C",
            "High" : 0.00000072,
            "Low" : 0.00000001,
            "Volume" : 166340678.42280999,
            "Last" : 0.00000005,
            "BaseVolume" : 17.59720424,
            "TimeStamp" : "2014-07-09T07:21:40.51",
            "Bid" : 0.00000004,
            "Ask" : 0.00000005,
            "OpenBuyOrders" : 18,
            "OpenSellOrders" : 18,
            "PrevDay" : 0.00000002,
            "Created" : "2014-05-30T07:57:49.637",
            "DisplayMarketName" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

I want a series of `arrays`, `NUMERIC` not `STRINGS`....preferably.

```
Dim MarketName(500) as string
Dim High(500) as Double
Dim Low(500) as Double
etc...
```

That can be used in the Windows Forms Application to populate text boxes,make graphs etc etc... All of that I can do.... long time programmer....
but I cant get the data out of the console in a usable format.... please help.

Comment: There are hundreds of posts here showing how to either parse or deserialize json.  You need to do some research, try something and post a specific programming question when you get stuck.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]